# sort ignoring less than and greater than characters

Tags: unix

sort command is ignoring character '<' and '>' characters for sorting.

```
$ cat 1
< word6
< word5
> word1
> word2
> word3
< word4
$ sort 1
> word1
> word2
> word3
< word4
< word5
< word6
$
```

I want to sort the content by first character ('<' has ascii code 60, '>' ascii code 62) also.
I want the below output from sort:

```
< word4
< word5
< word6
> word1
> word2
> word3
```

Is it possible to get above output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort considers your locale (language *and* character encoding). Depending on the language the same character code might be sorted differently.
It seems like you want to sort by ASCII codes. In this case, set the locale to `C`:

```
LC_ALL=C sort yourFile
```

prints the expected output. The system locale is *not* altered. Only this one `sort` command is affected.